# how to access part of a encoded (gb18020) string in python

Tags: python, encoding

I am encoding Chinese characters using gb18030 in python. I want to access part of the encoded string. For example, the string for 李 is: '\xc0\xee'. I want to extract 'c0' and 'ee' out of this. However, python is not treating '\xc0\xee' as a 8 character string, but as a 2 character string. How I do turn it into a 8 character string so that I could access the individual roman letters in it?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. repr() will do.

Comment: Please make sure to provide complete answer to the question even if it is your own question. Function name is generally not a good answer by itself.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
li = "李"
values = str(li.encode('gb18030'))
values = [i.strip("'") for i in values.split("\\x")[1:]]
```

---

```
print(values)
['c0', 'ee']
```

How do you use `repr()` to get the values you are looking for?